# mdframed and minipage

Tags: mdframed

I'm trying to find a way to use  mdframed to make separation of the frame to the next page but low knowledge does not help me. My effort is try and effect .... no results so far. I know there have been similar questions. But what I want is a way to keep the environment as shown in the example. Please for help.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\PlaisioBoxWidth}
\newsavebox{\KokkinoRoundedBox}
\newenvironment{RedBox}[1][\dimexpr\linewidth]
{\setlength{\PlaisioBoxWidth}{\dimexpr#1}
  \begin{lrbox}{\KokkinoRoundedBox}
    \begin{minipage}
      {\PlaisioBoxWidth}   }%
{
\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  % \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw node[draw=black,fill=red!15,rounded corners,%
    inner sep=1ex,text width=\PlaisioBoxWidth]%
    {\usebox{\KokkinoRoundedBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % \end{center}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{RedBox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{RedBox}
% 
\begin{RedBox}
 \lipsum[1-6]
\end{RedBox}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but I think you want to use `mdframed`. Below i have defined `MyRedBox` that sort of mimics your `minipage` but allows breaking over pages.  Your `minipage` is in red, and the `mdframed` version is in blue:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) package was used to show the page margins. Notice that your `minipage` environment goes into the margin. I assume you don't really want that behaviour so did not adjust the right margin for `mdframed`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum, showframe}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\PlaisioBoxWidth}
\newsavebox{\KokkinoRoundedBox}
\newenvironment{RedBox}[1][\dimexpr\linewidth]
{\setlength{\PlaisioBoxWidth}{\dimexpr#1}
  \begin{lrbox}{\KokkinoRoundedBox}
    \begin{minipage}
      {\PlaisioBoxWidth}   }%
{
\end{minipage}
  \end{lrbox}
  % \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw node[draw=black,fill=red!15,rounded corners,%
    inner sep=1ex,text width=\PlaisioBoxWidth]%
    {\usebox{\KokkinoRoundedBox}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % \end{center}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=blue!15, roundcorner=5pt, usetwoside=false, leftmargin=0.6cm]{MyRedBox}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{RedBox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{RedBox}
% 
\begin{MyRedBox}
 \lipsum[1-6]
\end{MyRedBox}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understandstand the question too :-)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, for more than two weeks I trying to fix them. Thank you very much @PeterGrill :-)